# Adding mcrypt to homestead on windows

Tags: php, laravel-4, homestead, mcrypt

I am trying to open an old Laravel 4 project on my recently created vm using vagrant homestead. However when I visit the project url it says
`Mcrypt PHP extension required.`

After browsing around for a solution on how to enable mcrypt most sources are saying to run this command in homestead `sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt`

But when ever I try this my terminal (gitbash) says:

`$ sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
bash: sudo: command not found`

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to terminal and not sure where to go from here.

How do I install mcrypt on windows for my laravel vm using vagrant and homestead?

Comment: Do not use mcrypt.  It's been abandoned for years and is considered insecure.

Comment: Yes i know mcrypt is outdated but i need it to view an old project

Comment: Install older php (5.6) and run the fpm on different tcp port or unix socket. Set up your vhost to proxypass to 5.6's socket. If you use [Ondrej's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej), that's quite trivial - `sudo apt-get install php5.6-*`. Nothing stops you from having multiple versions of php running, so if it's for an older project, use older php.